# How do I "Go to a different folder" in Outlook for Mac 2016?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2016

From the [Keyboard shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-navigating-Mail-in-Outlook-2016-ca79fe45-80e5-47dd-b7a0-841d4711ed53):

```
Go to a different folder   Ctrl+Y
```

Looking through the [Keyboard shortcuts for Outlook 2016 for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Outlook-2016-for-Mac-07ae68c8-b7af-4010-b225-324c04ac7335?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) I'm not seeing that shortcut available.

- How do I jump to or search for a folder in Outlook 2016 for Mac?

Comment: I would be interested if this behavior can at least be recreated if not natively part of the tool.

Comment: I'm also interested on this shortcut.  I'm trying to make Outlook take a smaller footprint on my screen (e.g. no side-panel) and start navigating folders and sections using the keyboard, just as can be done on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I might be super late with the reply here, but in case it helps  -

> Go to Folder... shortcut:     ^G